# Tkinter polygon edge resolution

Tags: python, tkinter, polygon

I am attempting to draw some polygons using tkinter. That is relatively easy. The problem is that the edges of the polygon are fairly pixelized/low resolution. See the example in the picture:

[image: Edge pixelization using polygon]

Is there a way to make the edges "smoother" (but not in the sense of using the "smoothing" option which ends up creating a circle). Hopefully I didn't miss something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: The term you're looking for is anti-aliasing. Check out http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-aggdraw.htm

Comment: Right! I couldn't think of the term. I'll check that out, thanks!